# How to select only true values from the tuple in python

Tags: pandas

How to select True columns only from below
'''
for i in cat:
    if i in df:
        uniques=((i,df[i].nunique()<6))
    print(uniques)
'''

('Exterior1st', False)
('Exterior2nd', False)
('MasVnrType', True)
('ExterQual', True)
('ExterCond', True)
('Foundation', False)
('BsmtQual', True)
('BsmtCond', True)
('BsmtExposure', True)
('BsmtFinType1', False)
('BsmtFinType2', False)
('Heating', False)
('HeatingQC', True)
('CentralAir', True)
('Electrical', True)
('KitchenQual', True)
('Functional', False)
('GarageType', False)
('GarageFinish', True)
('GarageQual', True)
('GarageCond', True)
('PavedDrive', True)
('SaleType', False)
('SaleCondition', False)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
tuples = [('Exterior1st', False), ('Exterior2nd', False), ('MasVnrType', True), ('ExterQual', True), ('ExterCond', True), ('Foundation', False), ('BsmtQual', True), ('BsmtCond', True), ('BsmtExposure', True), ('BsmtFinType1', False), ('BsmtFinType2', False), ('Heating', False), ('HeatingQC', True), ('CentralAir', True), ('Electrical', True), ('KitchenQual', True), ('Functional', False), ('GarageType', False), ('GarageFinish', True), ('GarageQual', True), ('GarageCond', True), ('PavedDrive', True), ('SaleType', False), ('SaleCondition', False)]
res = [tup for tup in tuples if any(i in tup for i in [True])] 
print(res)

[('MasVnrType', True), ('ExterQual', True), ('ExterCond', True), ('BsmtQual', True), ('BsmtCond', True), ('BsmtExposure', True), ('HeatingQC', True), ('CentralAir', True), ('Electrical', True), ('KitchenQual', True), ('GarageFinish', True), ('GarageQual', True), ('GarageCond', True), ('PavedDrive', True)]
```